# Is there any tool for preparing MIS using php,mysql,jquery or dojo

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dojo

I am just about to get into a project where the entire data is stored in only one table in a database. This table is to be shown in the form of a MIS report to the admin using PHP and javascript. I have created a front end for this using drop down menus etc so that data can be drilled into and all that. However It would be great if someone could tell me if there is some other tool which could make it look much more professional with more features like extracting data in form of csv or excel , and a much better views. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i think any of the prepackage Dojo themes for Dojo Grid look pretty professional. Are you not using the Grid?

As far as export CSV should be **really** easy. Just take the columns they have selected and loop over the table data doing something like `fputcsv($handle, array_diff_key($row, $selected));` and then send the file across for download. You could also export to a an xls (or xlsx) if you use something like [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).